# What underlying semantic notions connect 'luctor' to the PIE root *leug ‎(“bend, twist”)?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

> [ [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/luctor#Etymology) :] From Proto-Indo-European **lugsos*, from **leug* ‎(“bend, twist”). Cognates include Ancient Greek λύγος ‎(lúgos), Lithuanian lugnas, and Old Norse lykna.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=reluctance&allowed_in_frame=0) does not expose the PIE root directly, and [Uni. Texas's IE Lexicon](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/P1192.html) omits it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De Vaan confirms your etymology. Luctor means "to wrestle". When you're wrestling with someone, you writhe and twist your bodies, so it makes sense that a word for "bend, twist" should have acquired a sense like "wrestle".

Comment: Ernout and Meillet 2001 basically say the same thing: "sur la racine on ne peut proposer que des hypothèses peu consistantes. Souvent rapproché de "infléchir, assouplir les members"; c'aurait été d'abord un term du gymnase." I assume LePressentiment understands French, so no English translation.

Comment: @AlexB. +1. No need for Eng translation as presaged. Thank you for introducing me to http://www.amazon.com/Dictionnaire-%C3%A9tymologique-langue-latine-Collection/dp/2252033592.

Comment: @AlexB.: By the way, De Vaan always also takes E–M and W–H into account.